# printing out unordered map values prints out address

Tags: c++

```
for(auto& i : unorderedMap){
    cout << i.first << " " << cout << i.second << endl;
    cout << unorderedMap[i.first] << endl;
}
```

So this outputs

```
B2 0x6083e83
3  //B2 should be 3 instead of 0x6083e83
A2 0x6083e820
20 //A2 should be 20 instead of 0x6083e820
```

I thought the output should look like

```
B2 3
3   
A2 20
20
```

B2 and A2 are keys, and i.second prints out address, but when I access my unordredMap with my keys I get the actual values 3, and 20

I'm not sure I understand, shouldn't i.second return 3 and 20

Comment: `cout << i.first << " " << cout << i.second << endl;` - the 2nd `cout` is unnecessary.

Comment: When you print `cout` it gives you an addres of that object

Comment: oh yeah... sorry need sleep

Comment: You've got an extra `cout` in the first print statement.

Comment: Voting to close off-topic as a typo.